# How to use plot parametric function with discrete data?

Tags: plotting, functions, parametric-functions

You can easily create a ParametricPlot using the syntax `ParametricPlot[{fx, fy}, {t, tmin, tmax}]` when you have the functions `fx` and `fy` explicitly. However, what if you only have a discrete version of `{fx, fy}`? Can you still create a ParametricPlot?

I am considering trying this method using discrete data exported from another software. Here is a minimal working example:

```
fx = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
fy = Table[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]; 
ParametricPlot[{fx, fy}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I expect the output of the plot to closely resemble that of the continuous version.

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Maybe `ListPlot[Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}], Joined -> True]`.

Comment: @cvgmt thanks, it works. I sampled more points so it looks very similar to the continous version.

Answer (score 5):

We can eliminate the first common variable then get the co-relationship.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{fx[[;; , 2]], fy[[;; , 2]]}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
xy = Transpose[{fx[[All, 2]], fy[[All, 2]]}];

BSF = BSplineFunction[xy, SplineDegree -> 1];

ParametricPlot[BSF @ t, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], ColorData[97] @ 1, Point @ BSF["ControlPoints"]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ParametricPlot[{fx[[IntegerPart @ t, 2]], fy[[IntegerPart @ t, 2]]}, 
 {t, 1, Length @ fx}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated the expected output, could you update the answer as well?

Comment: @internet, updated.

Comment: `BSplineFunction[]` doesn't pass over the points except with the option `SplineDegree->1`. It's not visible in the graphics above. One can see this by reducing the number of points

Comment: Thank you @andre314; very good point. I updated with the option.

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 12.1.1.0  and got an error with `ColorData[97] @ #`. Also the mesh points are much more crowded than what you showed. Is that due to different version?

Comment: @internet, `ColorData[97] @ #` should be `ColorData[97] @ 1` (i  updated with the correction). Re crowded mesh points, it is probably version-related -- I am using _13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)_

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

fx = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
fy = Table[{t, Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
```

Use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)

```
ParametricPlot[{Interpolation[fx][t], Interpolation[fy][t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}),
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 2 Pi}},
   LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[t], 14]]]
```

[image]